# Single Page App : Back after login

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

Need your suggestions.

I have angularjs app, using ui.router for routing.

The users are first presented with a login screen, on login a grid is shown.
The grid is paginated.

Now if the user clicks on the browser back button, the user is taken to the login screen. 
1. Is this correct behavior  and would you suggest otherwise. 
2. Also if the user as moved to 3 page using pagination should the back button  take the user to the previous page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's entirely up to you to decide if that's the behavior you want or not.

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions Anony?

Answer (score 1):

1.) You could prevent the client to go back to login by using `$stateChangeStart`. For example like this:

```
/**
 * Before state change / page switch
 */
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, next, current, fromState, fromParams, options) {

    //verify login state
    if ($cookies.get('loggedIn') !== undefined) {
        if (next.templateUrl !== "views/login.html") {
            $timeout (function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('app.overview');
            }, 50);
        }
    }
});
```

2.) Create an URL for all pages inside your pagination so the user is able to go back / forward by using the browser history:

```
.state('app.list', {
    url: '/list/:pageId',
    templateUrl: 'views/list.html'
})
```

Change the URL on page click without reload by using `notify: false`:

```
$state.go('app.list', {pageId: yourNextdPageId}, {notify: false})
```